# What Happened To Maul When The Emperor Defeated Him?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-maul

In a certain episode with Darth Maul and Savage Oppress, Darth Sidious comes and kills Savage and also overpowers Maul himself.  *The Clone Wars* then switches to other subjects, and they don't show Maul again until Ahsoka finds him in Mandalore.

What happened to Maul during this time?  Is there any canon story around this time?  (I'm assuming this is not in any movie or series.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is answered in the comic miniseries *[Darth Maul, Son of Dathomir](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir)*. It's based on unproduced scripts from *The Clone Wars*' original sixth season and is considered canon, despite being published by Dark Horse.

In summary, Darth Sidious sent Maul to a Separatist prison to be interrogated, where he was freed by Death Watch.

Comment: Interesting.  Guess they didn't have time to talk about Asohka and do that backstory as well, although I think it's a bit of a plot hole without it.

Comment: @RBlong2us How so?

Comment: Cause all of a sudden he's back in a couple episodes, even though it was quite obvious the Emperor had defeated him and was planning to do something with him.  It gives me a sense of "What did I miss?"